# I have a list of list. Need to merge all the elements that is only "a" letters into a single string, moving the other elements down a position

Tags: python, list, loops

```
 
x1 = ['a','1','2','b','4']
x2 = ['a','a','2','b','4']
x3 = ['a','a','a','b','4']
x4 = ['a','1','2','b','4']
xxxx = x1,x2,x3,x4
name2f = []

for i in xxxx:
    a1 = i[0]
    b1 = i[1]
    c1 = i[2]

    if  a1.isalpha:
        if  b1.isalpha:
            if  c1.isalpha:
                print("false 3")
                p = i[0]+" "+i[1]+" "+i[2]
                i.remove(a1)
                i.remove(b1)
                i.remove(c1)
                name2f.append(p)
    elif a1.isalpha:
        if b1.isalpha:
            p = i[0]+" "+i[1]
            i.remove(a1)
            i.remove(b1)
            name2f.append(p)
    elif  a1.isalpha:
        name2f.append(a1)
        i.remove(a1)
        print("false 1")
    else: print("broken")
```

isalpha  and isdigit route does not seem to work nor does regex, not sure what is up. My results are print3 down the line. Not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: Btw, Python strings already have `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` functions, so why are you using regex?

Comment: The definition is valid; it defines a tuple containing a number of lists. Whether the references to `a` and `b` generate `NameError`s is another question.

Comment: i cleaned out the code. isdigit and isalpha nor regex is working.

Comment: You need to clarify "working". What outputs are you **expecting**? Please [edit] to show that

Comment: `str.isalpha()` is a function. You need to call with parenthesis...

Comment: The if, elif, elif are all checking the same value, `a1.isalpha:`. That value will be True for each list per the code. It appears you mean to implement some `and` logic. `if  a1.isalpha and b1.isalpha and  c1.isalpha:` Per my 2nd answer?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, went through the elements as a range and it worked:

```
 item = []
    for items in xxxx:
        for i in items[0:3]:
            if re.match(r'[A-Z]', i) and bool(re.search(r'[0-9]', i)) == False:
                item.append(i)
                items.remove(i)

    w = " ".join(item)
    print(w)
    print("")
    print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with code shown is `isalpha()` is a function. The function **object** `isalpha` is always non falsy.

Secondly, each of your if conditions check the exact same thing, so only the top one will run.

Also, your logic is only trying to generate something like `name2f = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'a']` since you only check first 3 elements, so the `b` strings are never looked at.

---

Break your code into two parts.

You can filter non-digits simply with

```
all_chars = [x for x in lst if not x.isdigit()]
```

Then, write a function to join all adjacent characters, such as

```
def collect_chars(lst):
  combined = lst[:1]
  result = []
  for val in lst[1:]:
    if val != combined[-1]:
      # current char not last seen char, dump the collected values so far
      result.append(''.join(combined))
      # and start a new string
      combined = [val]
    else:
      # keep adding matching strings
      combined.append(val)
  # if reached end of string, dump what has been collected so far
  result.append(''.join(combined))
  del combined

  return result
```

Then run both over the original list.

```
for i in xxxx:
  all_chars = [x for x in i if not x.isdigit()]
  lst = collect_chars(all_chars)
  print(lst)
```

Outputs

```
['a', 'b']
['aa', 'b']
['aaa', 'b']
['a', 'b']
```